# RESTful way to add an entity to another one (n:m relation) in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, has-and-belongs-to-many

this might be a very simple problem, with an easy solution, but I did not get it yet.

Assume I have the following two models:

```
class Task
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
end
```

Assume further there is a user named "wayne" with id=1 and a task named "go shopping" with id=2. What would be the RESTful way to create the relationship between them through the REST interface?

Adding a route like users/1/add_task/2 is more RPC-Style and not very RESTful. So how would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restful way would be to add a model that serves as a conjunction. The jointable would then get its own resource.
The join model could be called e.g. Subscription, or, if you don't find a fitting name, just call it TaskUser.
This part of the rails guides is relevant:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

```
class Task
  has_many :users, :through => "TaskUser"
end

class User
  has_many :tasks, :through => "TaskUser"
end

class TaskUser
  has_many :users
  has_many :tasks
end
```

When submitting a `POST to /taskusers` with a `user_id` and a `task_id` after you declared the route (e.g. by adding `resource TaskUser` in routes.rb), you create a link between the two objects. The controller should include something like this:

```
class TaskUsersController
  def create
    TaskUser.create(:task_id => params[:task_id], :user_id => params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

you are then able to access the tasks of a user simply by calling

```
user.tasks
```

Personally, i think there are situations where you dont need this solution as it creates a fair bit of overhead with the additional model and all that.

For example, i have an Item model and want to add Tags to it. It's a many-to-many association declared by `has_and_belongs_to_many` in each model, but i always add a Tag to an Item and not the other way round, so the former solution seems like a bit much. I then just add

```
put "/Items/#{item_id}/tags/#{tag_id}" => "items#add_tag"
```

to routes.rb. The ItemController:

```
class ItemController
  def add_tag
    item = Item.find_by_id(:item_id)
    tag = Tag.find_by_id(:tag_id)
    item.tags << tag
    item.save
  end
end
```

Hope that helps in any way, even if i just saw that the answer is a year late.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with

users/{userid}/tasks/

where a PUT to that location adds a task with {taskid} to the set; you can also (concurrently) have

tasks/{taskid}/users/

where a PUT to that location adds a user with {userid} to the set.

Comment: Am I getting it right, that I have to add this route by hand, and also add some code into the corresponding controller to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

What dou you think about this solution?

EDIT: Replace User with AssignmentSheet and Task with Assignment for this example to fit the original question.

Some routes:

```
# routes.rb
put "assignment_usage/assignment_sheet/:assignment_sheet_id/assignment/:assignment_id" => "assignment_usage#create"
  delete "assignment_usage/assignment_sheet/:assignment_sheet_id/assignment/:assignment_id" => "assignment_usage#destroy"
```

And the controller code:

```
# app/controllers/assignment_usage_controller.rb
class AssignmentUsageController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_instances

  # PUT /assignment_usage/assignment_sheet/:assignment_sheet_id/assignment/:assignment_id
  def create
    @assignment.assignment_sheets << @assignment_sheet
    redirect_to(@assignment_sheet, :notice => "Assignment has been successfully added.")
  end

  # DELETE /assignment_usage/assignment_sheet/:assignment_sheet_id/assignment/:assignment_id
  def destroy
    @assignment.assignment_sheets.delete @assignment_sheet
    redirect_to(@assignment_sheet, :notice => "Assignment has been successfully removed.")
  end

  private
  def load_instances
    @assignment_sheet = AssignmentSheet.find(params[:assignment_sheet_id])
    @assignment       = Assignment.find(params[:assignment_id])
  end
end
```

Maybe it is a little bit more clear to use a seperate resource for this.